# Updating table with EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I  am using a plist file inorder to fill my table cells , now I added [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) API to update my cells , but I do not know how can I match  my plist url file with this API

```
//this is my plist code that load from server 
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/news.plist"];
     titles = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url] retain];
```

EDITED :

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Data Source Loading / Reloading Methods

- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource{

    //  should be calling your tableviews data source model to reload
    //  put here just for demo
    _reloading = YES;
    [self.tableView reloadData];  

}

- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData{

    //  model should call this when its done loading
    _reloading = NO;
    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:self.tableView];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{ 

    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate Methods

- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

    [self reloadTableViewDataSource];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

}

- (BOOL)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceIsLoading:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

    return _reloading; // should return if data source model is reloading

}

- (NSDate*)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceLastUpdated:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

    return [NSDate date]; // should return date data source was last changed

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to call `reloadData`and that will refresh your `dataSource`. This logic should be the same for a "pull to refresh" feature as well.

Comment: do you mean something like this ? `[self.tableView reloadData];` in which function I should put this code ? see my edited Q

Comment: Yes. By the looks of it `egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh ` calls a method that already as `reloadData`. You gotta figure out if your controller is a UITableViewController, if so, then self.tableView should be correct. If you named your TableView, then you would need to reference it.

Comment: I tried it but nothing happen , also this code : `[self reloadTableViewDataSource];` consider that my table view data loads from server